# npm WARN firebase-functions-test@0.1.3 requires a peer of firebase-admin@^5.12.0 but none is installed

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

getting this message when using firebase-functions-test

> npm WARN firebase-functions-test@0.1.3 requires a peer of
>   firebase-admin@^5.12.0 but none is installed

what changes I need to make in the package.json file to resolve this message

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {...},
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.4.2",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.3",
    "prettier": "^1.13.7",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.15.0",
    "typescript": "~2.8.3",
  }
}
```

if I change the "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0" to "firebase-admin": "^5.12.2

I get this one

> npm WARN firebase-functions@2.0.5 requires a peer of
>   firebase-admin@~6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself.

What is the correct way to handle these warnings

Comment: Have you tried downgrading firebase-functions to a lower version, 1.1.0 maybe? Try that with firebase-admin 5.12.2

Comment: It's probably OK to just ignore the warnings.  I suspect that admin SDK API didn't change so much in 6.0.0 that it would break firebase-functions-test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following @DougStevenson recommendation, ignoring this error

> It's probably OK to just ignore the warnings. I suspect that admin SDK
>   API didn't change so much in 6.0.0 that it would break
>   firebase-functions-test.